# Digital signing of PDF

Tags: php, pdf, digital-signature, wkhtmltopdf, digital-certificate

I am currently using WKHTMLTOPDF to generate PDF in my application.

Now the requirement is to digitally sign the pdf (not placing of watermark or a sign image), something which can really authenticate that the pdf generate is from the app ONLY.

I looked into this plugin http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-signer/details/
but it is paid.

Can some one help me in signing the pdf ??

And other questions are most welcome.

FYI -  I am using PHP as server side language.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Swap pdf components use something like tcpdf, specifically see this example http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_016.phps

Comment: I too have looked into that link, but i have many different pdf's that need and swapping with take much longer time. Any other solutions ??

Comment: not really write your pdf creation as a function so you'll only have to do the change over once across all your code then in future if you need to change anything you just change the function. reusable code is your friend

Comment: @Dave yes, i have created a function, but the need to change the design for every PDF... right! ??

Comment: use templates and switch templates according to what layout you want